# Why is Navigation View Controller returning zero View Controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

For some reason, this code returns 0 elements:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
NSLog(@"numero: %d", viewControllers.count);
```

I am reaching my current ViewController (B), from viewController (A), by calling:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NumericKeyboard" sender:self];
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: `self.navigationController` is probably `nil`. Are you sure you are in a navigation controller?

Comment: What type of segue is it?

Comment: Is `[self navigationController]` nil?

Comment: My storyboard, has a Navigation Controller. I did this by embeding my first view controller in a Navigation Controller. I just checked, and yes, self.navigationController is nil!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932137/ios-development-what-are-some-reasons-that-self-navigationcontroller-viewcon

Comment: Any suggestions? current viewController was performed by a segue. Should't it know self.navigationController?

Comment: your code is omplete work may be mistake in performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: It's not a push segue. Wow, but making it a push segue fixes. I do not want it to be a push segue, however. I need my transition to be vertical.

Comment: @MarcusAdams this makes it a diferent question, if you'd be so kind to give an answer I will accept it as correct. Now I have to figure out how to make a push to transition vertically.

Comment: Appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the segue to view controller B is not a push segue, view controller B will not be in the stack of view controllers owned by the navigation controller.

Therefore, `[self navigationController]` will be `nil` when called against view controller B.

If you need view controller B to be in the stack automatically, you must change the segue to a push segue.

Alternatively, you can manually add the controller to the stack.